# Rows to Nested array

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP is there any function that make this row (which come from DB)

Source array structure:

```
[1]=>array(
   ["TYPE"] => 'FRUIT'
   ["VALUE"] => 'BANANA' 
)
[2]=>array(
   ["TYPE"] => 'FRUIT'
   ["VALUE"] => 'ORANGE'
)
```

Data Sample

```
fruit|apple
fruit|orange
fruit|strawberry

animal|rabbit
animal|buffalo
animal|ant

goods|scissor
goods|cutter
```

easily Become nested array:

```
array(
fruit => array('apple', 'orange', 'strawberry'),
animal => array('rabbit', 'buffalo', 'ant'),
goods => array('cutter', 'scissors'),
)
```

Based on it's type similarity.

Comment: are you getting this rows from database.table

Comment: Is it only two level or more than two level ?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra two or more,, it identify from if in same group then insert to same array index

Comment: can you show the actual array as it is?

Comment: @WildanMuhlis : What I mean is, will your string be like this : `fruit|apple | greenappale` ???, here you can see two `|`..Check my answer

Comment: @WildanMuhlis,I updated my answer,Please check it

Answer (score 0):

> In PHP is there any function that make this row

Nope, there is no ready-made function for this.
You have to write a program which would parse your strings and put them in array

Or you have to change your input source format. For JSON for example, as it can be parsed with the very single function you're asking for.

If you have these lines stored in DB this very way - you have to change it to more sensible structure, **storing categories apart from items.**

In general, you have to get your groups right from the loop used to get the data from database.

For example, [PDO has some [silly] magic for you:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-1023)

```
<?php

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Group values by the first column */
var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP));
?>
```

Which does the very job you're asking for.
However, it is very easy to simulate this behavior with whatever else API

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this example,

```
         <?php
         $result=array();
         $data = array(array("TYPE"=> 'FRUIT',"VALUE"=> 'BANANA' ),array("TYPE" => 'FRUIT',"VALUE"=> 'ORANGE'));
        foreach($data as  $temp)
        {
        $result[$temp['TYPE']][]=$temp['VALUE'];
        }
         print_r($result);
       ?>
```

**Output**

```
    Array ( [FRUIT] => Array ( [0] => BANANA [1] => ORANGE ) )
```